# What is it called? I want to process the "events" that a CLR DLL produces

Tags: events, dll, clr

So I am a Visual Basic 6 developer moving over to CLR and need an answer to a real newb question.

In Visual Basic 6, if you had an ActiveX control, you could reference that control and then have a statement essentially saying:

Public WithEvents YourControl  (Emphasis on the "WithEvents" keyword)

What happen is that in Visual Basic you would then have a set of event handler functions for that control.  You could simply choose them from a drop down list and an empty handler would be generated.

I am looking for the equivalent of that in VS2008 (Winform).  How do I access that functionality in the Visual Studio 2008 IDE?  I have the CLR DLL project referenced in my Winform project.  I just need to know how to get access to the functions/classes of that CLR DLL.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "C#" instead of "CLR"?

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on the language you're using.

**If you're using Visual Basic .NET**

The syntax is actually the same. In all .NET languages, events are simply `delegates`, which are basically function pointers that can point to zero or more functions of identical signatures.

The `WithEvents` keyword isn't *absolutely* necessary to handle events in VB.NET, but it does provide the developer with the ability to use legacy VB-style event handlers (and this is how the designer does it, as well). It can be done just as you're familiar with, like this

```
Private WithEvents YourControl as Control

Private Sub ClickFunction(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles YourControl.Click
    'do things
End Sub
```

To handle an event on an object without the `WithEvents` keyword, use `AddHandler`

```
AddHandler YourControl.Click, AddressOf ClickFunction

Private Sub ClickFunction(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
    'do things
End Sub
```

If you're interested in viewing the events in the combobox at the top of the editor, all you need is the variable to be declared with the `WithEvents` keyword. Just locate the variable you're interested in in the menu on the left, then the events should appear in the menu on the right.

**If you're using C# .NET**

There isn't any functionality like this in C#. All event handlers must be attached explicitly, like this

```
private Control YourControl;

private void ClickFunction(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff
}

// to attach, this goes somewhere in code

//...
YourControl.Click += ClickFunction;
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

In event broadcaster class:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

void OnMyEvent()
{
    if (MyEvent != null)
        MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

In event reciever class:

```
obj.MyEvent += new EventHandler(obj_MyEvent);

void obj_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something as a result of the event here
}
```

Syntax is in C#, VB.NET is similar

Comment: While the syntax for event declaration and invocation is similar, adding a delegate is not.

Comment: AddHandler ... AddressOf ... looks similar to me, just more verbose. Although, he did ask for "CLR"; maybe that means ldftn ... callvirt instance void BroadcasterClass::add_MyEvent(class System.EventHandler) ? ;)